# Who is starting my ssh-agent, and why won't it properly terminate?

Tags: ssh, login, raspbian, openssh, ssh-agent

This is a problem I've been having for a long time, but every time I try to figure something out I get lost, so I figured I'd better ask here where maybe someone more experienced could help me.

### Background

My Raspberry Pi is running Raspbian Jessie, and I use SSH often to login into it and execute commands remotely. During my first SSH sessions I noticed that an `ssh-agent` process was spawned **on the RPi** every time I logged in, but never killed when `exit`ing: logging in and out several times caused a bunch of `ssh-agent` processes to be spawned just to be left hanging there doing nothing. Fiddling around and reading man pages and answers here and there I recently understood the purpose of `ssh-agent`, and I also learned that it should normally get killed when logging out, so I began to ask myself why it wasn't. Furthermore, I noticed that issuing `source ~/.bashrc` causes another instance of `ssh-agent` to be spawned. I read on [the relative man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent) that the environment variable `SSH_AGENT_PID` should be defined because the `ssh-agent` program should be started within an `eval` to execute its output and define such variables, which are then used by other SSH-related commands, including `ssh-agent -k` (to kill the agent relative to the current session), so I ran `echo $SSH_AGENT_PID` and `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, but they were both empty. I suddenly realized: probably the process doesn't get killed on logout because `ssh-agent -k` tries to read its PID from the environment variable which is not set.

### The problem

Since `ssh-agent` is not being killed on logout, and this for sure happens because the needed environment variables aren't set, it can only mean one thing: **whoever calls `ssh-agent` on login probably doesn't do it in the proper way (which would be `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`)**. So I thought: well, what's the problem? I'll just find whichever configuration file, service, or login script gets executed to start the agent and manually fix it! **Where on earth could it be?**

### What I've tried

Since I noticed that an `ssh-agent` is spawned every time I call `source ~/.bashrc`, this was the first file I inspected, but nothing there even remotely referenced anything related to SSH. **I kept searching using `vi` for the string `ssh` inside all the following files, but found nothing**:

```
~/.bashrc
~/.profile
/etc/bash.bashrc
/etc/profile
/etc/profile.d/ (every file in this folder)
/etc/environment
```

Is there some more file that could be involved in `source ~/.bashrc`? I don't really know.

Then **I searched for relevant `systemd` services**, but only found `ssh.service`, which is `WantedBy=multi-user.target`, and therefore is not run on login (and well, that's obvious since this is the SSH server daemon).

I also **tried moving every single file in my `/home/pi` folder to a temporary folder** and logging out and back in again, but `ssh-agent` still spawned.

Eventually, I also fired the last shot I had in the chamber: I ran `find / -name 'ssh-agent'` as root, which only printed `/usr/bin/ssh-agent`, an executable, so **I created a fake executable which basically only logged the parent command**:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
ps -o args= $PPID        > /home/pi/LOG
cat /proc/$PPID/cmdline >> /home/pi/LOG
```

I renamed the real `/usr/bin/ssh-agent` and replaced it with the fake one setting the right permissions/user/group, ran `source ~/.bashrc` again, then printed the `LOG` file:

```
-bash
-bash
```

Not a single clue on what is going on.

### Some more details

I'm adding some more details, I don't know if they could be helpful or not, but you know... better safe than sorry.

- Here's my [`.bashrc`](https://pastebin.com/Uai4j4Mc).
- **I created a new user named `dummy` using `useradd -m dummy`, and logging into it doesn't start any `ssh-agent`** (I feel like this could mean something). The `diff /home/pi/.bashrc /home/dummy/.bashrc` shows basically nothing (just a comment I made), same for `diff /home/pi/.profile /home/dummy/.profile`.
- The agent socket is created without problem even though `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is not set:

  ```
  pi:~$ ls -lAh /tmp/ssh-vQRTAyj7DJry/
  total 0
  srw------- 1 pi pi 0 Jan 28 03:12 agent.1328
  ```

  Not sure why, but the number on the socket filename is always the one immediately before the PID of the `ssh-agent` process.
- Snippet from `htop`:

  ```
   PID  USER  PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR  S  Command
     1  root   20   0  5472  3900  2728  S  /sbin/init
  1329  pi     20   0  3696   224    16  S  └─ ssh-agent -s
  ```
- Installed packages matching `ssh`:

  ```
  pi:~$ apt list --installed | grep ssh
  libpam-chksshpwd/oldstable,now 1.1.8-3.1+deb8u2+rpi3 armhf [installed]
  libssh-gcrypt-4/oldstable,now 0.6.3-4+deb8u2 armhf [installed,automatic]
  libssh2-1/oldstable,now 1.4.3-4.1+deb8u1 armhf [installed,automatic]
  openssh-client/oldstable,now 1:6.7p1-5+deb8u4 armhf [installed,automatic]
  openssh-server/oldstable,now 1:6.7p1-5+deb8u4 armhf [installed,automatic]
  openssh-sftp-server/oldstable,now 1:6.7p1-5+deb8u4 armhf [installed,automatic]
  ssh/oldstable,now 1:6.7p1-5+deb8u4 all [installed]
  sshpass/oldstable,now 1.05-1 armhf [installed]
  ```
- Searching for `ssh-agent -s` recursively using `grep` in `/etc` and `/lib` yields no results.
- I have no desktop environment installed, but I have a `/etc/X11` folder with some configuration files in it. I tried renaming the folder to something else and rebooting just in case, but the process still gets spawned, so *apparently* that doesn't have much to do with this.

---

### Conclusion

Now, to make it as simple as possible, I've only got two questions:

1. **Where and how is this `ssh-agent` spawned, who issues the command?**
2. **Why doesn't it get called in the proper way, without setting the needed environment variables, and therefore leaving the process to hang there indefinitely?**

Comment: I do wonder what you have in your `~/.bashrc` then.

Comment: @ilkkachu well, [here you go](https://pastebin.com/Uai4j4Mc)...

Answer (score 1):

I know a couple possible reasons:

- if you're using `libpam-ssh`, it can automatically start a SSH agent for you as part of a session start-up, and even automatically load your keys if they either have no passphrase or their passphrase is the same as your login password.
- if you are using `gpg-agent`, it can optionally perform the task of the `ssh-agent` too. Its shut-down is handled differently, so there will be only the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable, not the `SSH_AGENT_PID`
- if you have SSH-agent (e.g. PuTTY's Pageant) running on your workstation and make a SSH connection with agent forwarding enabled (and the remote `sshd` allows it), on the remote host you will again see only `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` without the `SSH_AGENT_PID`... because the agent socket goes to `sshd` which tunnels it back to your local workstation's SSH agent.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but unfortunately none of those options apply to me. I don't have `libpam-ssh`; both `SSH_AGENT_PID` and `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` are unset (the socket is of course present anyway); I don't use `gpg-agent` and don't have agent forwarding enabled on PuTTY. I'm really lost :\

Answer (score 1):

This is old question but if you came here looking to find out what sets the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable *aside from all the other places mentioned*, then the answer is `sshd`.

`sshd` would set the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` if you enabled agent forwarding, `AllowAgentForwarding yes` in `/etc/sshd_config` (enabled by default).

There is no way to configure sshd to use a different path for `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` because it seems the path has been [hard coded](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/bef92346c4a808f33216e54d6f4948f9df2ad7c1/session.c#L200).

`SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is not set if agent forwarding is disabled.

`man sshd_config`:

> Note that disabling agent forwarding does not improve security unless
> users are also denied shell access, as they can always install their
> own forwarders.