# Why does `ssh-agent -k` not kill ssh-agent (macOS), or why is `SSH_AGENT_PID` not set?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

I'm trying to troubleshoot a sudden outbreak of short-lived SSH connections. These connections are initiated from my Mac (MBP, Catalina 10.15.6, `zsh`) to some of the Linux *"appliances"* that live on my network here - in particular the *Raspberry Pies*. After the connections terminate, they leave the message `client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe` in the terminal.

**However:** That's offered only as background in case it's related to **my immediate question**:

#### Why does the command `ssh-agent -k` not kill `ssh-agent`?

It appears to fail because the environment variable `SSH_AGENT_PID` is not set. I have guessed that based on what I see in my Mac terminal app:

***1. list *ssh-related processes*:***

```bsh
% pgrep -f ssh       
2138
75076
75942
75943
75944
% ps 2138     
  PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
 2138   ??  S      0:00.26 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -l
```

PID `2138` is `ssh-agent`, the other PIDs are active `ssh` connections to Raspberries or Ubuntu box - all Linux.

***2. kill `ssh-agent` IAW `man ssh-agent`:***

From `man ssh-agent`:

> ssh-agent [-c | -s] -k
> -k      Kill the current agent (given by the SSH_AGENT_PID environment variable).

```bsh
% ssh-agent -k 
SSH_AGENT_PID not set, cannot kill agent  
% sudo ssh-agent -k  
SSH_AGENT_PID not set, cannot kill agent

% echo $SSH_AGENT_PID

%
```

I can kill `ssh-agent` using `kill 2138`, or with `pkill ssh-agent`, and so it ***seems*** that perhaps the answer is ***Apple's version of `ssh-agent` doesn't provision the environment variable `SSH_AGENT_PID`***. But if that's the answer, it raises another question: ***Is there a valid reason for not assigning the environment variable `SSH_AGENT_PID`?***

Also note that a [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420124/who-is-starting-my-ssh-agent-and-why-wont-it-properly-terminate). However, the OP for that question didn't identify his SSH client host was macOS. He also indicated `SSH_AGENT_PID` was not set, but seemed concerned only with how `ssh-agent` was started. In my case (macOS), `ssh-agent` is started when an ssh connection is initiated. I found other Q&A in the "Similar Questions" suggestion box; I read a few of them, but none seem the same as mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1734787/282362).

From the `man` [page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-agent.1.html):

> When ssh-agent
> is started, it prints the shell commands required to set its
> environment variables, which in turn can be evaluated in the
> calling shell, for example `` eval `ssh-agent -s` ``

So running `ssh-agent` just *shows* the commands to set the environment variables, not actually *sets* them, unless you use `eval`.

Comment: Could you please explain why `ssh-agent` would only print the shell commands - rather than actually running those commands. That just does not seem like a logical thing for `ssh-agent` to do.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I think it has something to do with the ability of programs to affect the shell. I think setting environment (and shell) variables is something only the shell can do itself or by using `export`. Since `ssh-agent` can't set the variables for you, the next best thing is to show you how.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on ubuntu 18.04. After using `pidof ssh-agent` to get the IDs, the following worked for me:

```
export SSH_AGENT_PID=<pid>
eval `ssh-agent -k`
```

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this question, so bear with me, but I think my question was, "Why isn't the environment set properly in macOS?" Unless I'm missing something, your answer sets the env var manually, but that must be repeated at each boot??